# How can I import tif file in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, geotiff-tiff, import

While importing TIFF image to GRASS GIS, I get an error:

```
Location PROJ_INFO is:
name: Lambert Conformal Conic
proj: lcc
datum: nad83
a: 6378137.0
es: 0.006694380022900787
lat_1: 36.16666666666666
lat_2: 34.33333333333334
lat_0: 33.75
lon_0: -79
x_0: 609601.22
y_0: 0
no_defs: defined

Dataset PROJ_INFO is:
name: Lat/Lon
proj: ll
datum: wgs84
ellps: wgs84
no_defs: defined

ERROR:
You can use the -o flag to r.in.gdal to override this check and use the location definition for the dataset.
Consider generating a new location from the input dataset using the 'location' parameter.
Provide rolution to remove this error -o in GRASS GIS
```

Answer (score 2):

In GRASS, location and dataset should share the same projection.

`On-the-fly-reprojection` is only available in advanced GIS packages like QGIS or Arcgis.

To change the projection, use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to a different filename outside of GRASS.

Comment: (Fri Sep 26 12:12:18 2014)                                                      
r.out.gdal input=manj@PERMANENT output=C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\doit\1409825221.tif
Exporting to GDAL data type: UInt16
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value 65535 will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting to GDAL raster
r.out.gdal complete.
(Fri Sep 26 12:12:20 2014) Command finished (2 sec)

Comment: even also Iam unable to view map on display screen

Comment: How can I give same projection

Comment: Now I changed to same projection again giving error and no map display on screen (Fri Sep 26 12:32:04 2014)                                                      
r.in.gdal input=E:\cdnh43e_v1.1r1.tif output=cdnh43e_v1                         
Projection of input dataset and current location appear to match
r.in.gdal complete. Raster map <cdnh43e_v1> created.
(Fri Sep 26 12:32:06 2014) Command finished (1 sec)                             
Command 'd.rast -o map=cdnh43e_v1@PERMANENT' failed
Command 'd.rast -o map=cdnh43e_v1@PERMANENT' failed

Comment: Layer Manager giving this message                    Command 'd.rast -o map=cdnh43e_v1@PERMANENT' failed        and  r.buffer cmd prompt giving this message  Reading input raster map <cdnh43e_v1@PERMANENT>...
Writing output raster map <bufout>...

Comment: (Mon Sep 29 16:52:29 2014)                                                      
r.terraflow elevation=cdnj43v@PERMANENT filled=cdnflood direction=cdnflowdir swatershed=cdnsink accumulation=cdnflowacc tci=cdntci                                                  
ERROR: cell file cdnj43v resolution differs from current region
(Mon Sep 29 16:52:29 2014) Command finished (0 sec)

Answer (score 1):

As Andre mentioned in GRASS your LOCATION coordinate system **must** match the coordinate system of the data being input. You can create a new LOCATION when you input the original tiff file by using the `location=` parameter.

For example:

```
r.in.gdal input=E:\cdnh43e_v1.1r1.tif output=cdnh43e_v1 location=LCC
```

Now run:

```
g.region raster=cdnh43e_v1
```

to set your current extent and resolution to match the original raster, and you should be good to go with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

On-the-fly reprojection, to the spatial reference system of the Location in which the GeoTIFF is to be imported, is possible since the introduction of `r.import`.

From https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.import.html:

Imports raster data into a GRASS raster map using GDAL library and reprojects on the fly.