# Import .tif file to server and display it in PuTTy (grass gis)

Tags: raster, grass-gis, import, server

I am quite new in working on server and have one problem with importing file.

I have .TIFF files in my computer and would like to send them to server which I work with using PuTTy and GRASS. I tried to use WinSCP to copy files to my folder in server, but I am not sure if it is enough to display it in GRASS via PuTTy (anyways, does not work when I try).

I tried to use: `r.in.gdal` and `r.import`. As well just to display file using `d.mon` and then `d.rast filename`.

It's basic problem, but please, tell me step by step how to do that to be able to display raster.

Comment: related the gis part https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115250/how-can-i-import-tif-file-in-grass-gis can you ftp your files to your server?

Comment: Warning 1: Could not find one of the X, Y or Z column names
in header line. Defaulting to the first 3 columns
ERROR 1: Couldn't determine X spacing (This is my problem when I try to import .TIFF file via GRASS)

Comment: I think you need a .tfw file for the your tiff to calculate pixel dimensions to real world scale http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/resources/doc/grass5/html/r.in.tiff.html

Comment: Unfortunately I work on "bigger" files, hyperspectral photos. I created an NDVI in R and then exported it to tiff. Now I would like to do other things in GRASS. Command r.in.tiff does not work with my file.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really GIS related, rather you seem to be having problems working remotely on a server. Does the server have X windows running? When you give the command `d.mon start=wx0` does a windows open on your local machine? If not, then you might not have the "ForwardX11" option enabled in Putty. What's more, if you're using Putty, then you must be on a windows computer. What OS is on the server?

After doing `r.in.gdal`, you can run `g.list rast` to check if the tiff was indeed imported. Then, as always, don't forget to set the computational region: `g.region -p rast=<imported raster>`.

Comment: I already solved my problem. File was just copied to catalog and I saw it using mc, but not in g.list rast. At the end I created new folder and loaded new mapset, copied file there, then chosed option: "Read projection and datum from a georefferenced data file." Now everything works. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remote connection using different protocols (particular ssh) is using [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). It has built in X server which will up when necessary and another cool thing you can have multiple tabs with sessions.